# Нужно принять сообщение от конкретного id (telegram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Мне нужно принимать сообщения от конкретного id-telegram (модератора). То есть если подтвердит, то пост опубликуется, если нет, то не опубликуется.

Приведенный ниже код не работает, не додумаюсь как можно получать сообщение от конкретного id

**Бот, после того, как получил данные от какого-то пользователя -> отправляет модератору на проверку
-> модератора подтверждает или отклоняет -> из данных формируется пост и публикуется в канал (если модератора конечно подтвердит**

````
if message.chat.id == **id модератора**:
    if message.text == "✅Пост":

        if src:
            bot.send_photo(**id канала**, open(src,'rb'), caption=f"переменные и тд")        
            bot.send_message(**id модератора**, "*Пост опубликован*", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode="Markdown")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '✅ *Спасибо, ваши данные успешно прошли модерацию и опубликованы на канал!*', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode="Markdown")

        else:
            bot.send_message(**id канала**, f"переменные и тд")
            bot.send_message(**id модератора**, "*Пост опубликован*", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode="Markdown")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '✅ *Спасибо, ваши данные успешно прошли модерацию и опубликованы на канал!*', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode="Markdown")

    elif message.text == "❌Игнор":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ *Простите, данные не прошли модерацию. Повторите попытку.*', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode="Markdown")
        bot.send_message(**id модератора**, "*Пост проигнорирован*", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode="Markdown")```
````

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Comment: Значит не работает моя задумка, то есть самое первое условие не выолняется (if)

Comment: Ну так значит вы не тот айди вписали или промазали с типом данных

Comment: Ну так в том и заключается вопрос, правильно ли я вообще делаю и если нет, то как правильно?